# Json.net incorrect parsing of date e.g. 2009-01-01T03:00:00.000Z

Tags: c#, .net, json, datetime, json.net

I'm having issues while parsing a Json object with Json.NET using  `DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local` in my `JsonSerializerSettings`.

The Json input is

```
{
'CreatedDate': '2009-01-01T03:00:00.000Z'
}"
```

and the value for de CreatedDate property  is `'2009-01-01T01:00:00-02:00'`

If I try with another value, e.g. 1 year later, `CreatedDate :'2010-01-01T03:00:00.000Z'`, the library works fine.

Here's my example, in a ConsoleApplication

```
string json = @"
{
    'CreatedDate': '2009-01-01T03:00:00.000Z'
}";

var value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local
});

Console.Write(value);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: What is the expected result? And how does the year later look like then?

Comment: Why is this wrong? What is the result in the other case? Why is that correct? What locale are you running this in? Did that locale have the same daylight savings rules in effect in 2009 and 2010? What happens if you do `DateTimeOffset.Parse("2009-01-01T01:00:00Z").ToLocalTime()` and `DateTimeOffset.Parse("2010-01-01T01:00:00Z").ToLocalTime()` in that locale?

Comment: Note that `T01:00:00-02:00` _is_ `T03:00:00.000Z`.

Comment: What's the error you're getting even , works fine for me

Comment: The json value is DateTime UTC. If you convert it to local (based on where you are), then the value is correct.

Comment: You've *explicitly* said that you want the value converted to a local time. `DateTimeZoneHandling.Local` is documented as: "Treat as local time. If the DateTime object represents a Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), it is converted to the local time." So what's incorrect about this? And which time zone is this?

Comment: In fact value is correct. 
But i don't understand why parsing '2009-01-01T03:00:00.000Z' results in a datetimeoffset with -02:00 timezone, at 1:00 a.m. 
and '2010-01-01T03:00:00.000Z' results in a -03:00 timezone at 00:00 a.m.

Comment: I'm ussing Argentinian timezone (-03:00)

Comment: According to https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hora_oficial_argentina, the parsed value is correct. @JonHanna was right about daylight saving rules. 
Thanks!

Comment: Behaviour was correct per the nature of the problem domain.